# How to literally translate this: 这对于那些想看又买不起书的人来说?

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

随着小人书的流行，出现了从事租书业务的小人书摊，这对于那些想看又买不起书的人来说，只用很少的钱就能看一本，毫无疑问是件大好事。

Hi all, this is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 20.

I need your help about the literal translation of this: 这对于那些想看又买不起书的人来说

I have reached on that point:

这(this)对于(concerning)那些(those)想(to want)看(to see or to read)又(emphatic character)买不起(cannot afford to buy)书(book)的人(people)来说(concerning)

I don't know how are the 对于 and 来说 connected and what they mean. Also, whether I am right about the 又, and how to make all this clause make sense.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would interpret/translate the sentence as below: (Note some changes are necessary for differences in grammatical structures.)

这 = this (previously stated phenomenon - 随着小人书的流行，出现了从事租书业务的小人书摊),

对于(as to, for)那些(those)想看(wanted to read)又(but)买不起书(couldn't afford the book)的人(people's)来说(concern).

this, as to those, who wanted to read but couldn't afford the book, people's concern, .....